# firebase encryption or not?

Tags: python, android, firebase

I'm new to the world of Android development. Self taught in python and still learning. I've spent basically 10 - 14 hours a day every day for 7 months developing a app(cause im addicted to programming now hehe)

Anyway my app is functional but not yet on play store but i'm looking into it, as a result it got me thinking about another rabbit hole to go down...

The app collects location data, phone numbers and some other sensitive data. That data gets stored on firebase realtime database as a JSON. Because firebase is "google" owned, its https and you need to be authorised to access it, in the eyes of proper developers and google, etc. would the JSON data i'm storing of sensitive info be classed as "secure" on firebase or do i have to learn about python encryption and stuff as well ?

Comment: You **REALLY** don't want to be handling any personal data (especially location data, phone number) of other people in the cloud as a hobbyist. That's "terrible idea and potential financial ruin" territory.

Comment: I disagree with the closure of this question. It's perfectly legitimate in the context of this site. While "how secure is secure enough?" would be highly opinion-based, the question as stated is asking **if database security alone makes an app secure**. That is not an opinion-based question and can be easily answered by anyone with a security-related background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No

No, it's not necessarily secure because of the location.

Security is a multi-layered discipline that involves awareness of threat vectors, sensitivity to the threat environment and consideration of the data stored, not to mention legal requirements and financial risks!

### Multi-layered Security

To use a concrete example, imagine an extremely "secure" vault with 15-inch thick steel walls. Inside is a priceless treasure trove. However, for the sake of convenience, the owner of the vault has left the key taped to the front door and for the sake of cost has not hired security guards or paid for cameras.

While the vault may be impressive, the way in which it is used makes it an easy target for anyone who wants to break in and steal the contents.

Your firebase database may be physically secure (since it is located inside of a Google warehouse somewhere), but your app holds the keys to the database. If your app is easy to hack into, then the security of your database is compromised.

When we say that security is "multi-layered", it means that you shouldn't be overly-reliant on any one layer of security. Perhaps your database has a password. But if the password is compromised, then all of that data is now compromised. Likewise, if your data is encrypted, but the encryption key is compromised, then all of your data is compromised. But if your database requires a password AND the data is encrypted, then an attacker would need both the password and the encryption key. Having one would not be enough. This is an example of multi-layered security.

### Security Doesn't Stop at Your Database

Unfortunately, the need to access data requires, by definition, a breach of your security walls around the database. Again, to use a concrete example, this is like the classic movie trope of a laundry truck entering a maximum security prison. All the barbed wire and guards may be undone by the perfectly ordinary and expected laundry truck driving out the front gate. So in addition to database security, you need to consider app security.

For example, how easy is it for a user to spoof another user in your app? It doesn't matter if your database has many layers of security if an attacker can just use your app to access data for any and all users. (For the sake of this conversation, your "app" includes the service endpoints which your locally installed Android app uses to communicate with the server, which can be easily sniffed out by even an amateur hacker.)

### No One-Size-Fits-All Advice

Security is a non-trivial topic and so it's not possible to give you advice on how to secure your app and database. The best advice I can give is to be very thoughtful about what you choose to store. If you are going to have a central database, then assume it will be breached and all the contents leaked. How bad will that be for you? If it will expose you to legal or financial risk, then it may be cost-effective to hire a professional who can help you provide the necessary security for your app. Note that privacy laws are very complicated and vary exceedingly across jurisdictions, so if you are going to store sensitive user data you might need to consult a lawyer.

Here's a quick handful of laws you may need to consider when storing sensitive user data, but there are many, many more:

- USA's [COPPA (Children's Online Privacy Protection Act)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children%27s_Online_Privacy_Protection_Act)
- The EU's [GDPR (General Data Protection Regulation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation)
- California's [CCPA (California Consumer Privacy Act)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Consumer_Privacy_Act)

However, it sounds like this is a hobby. If so, then consider alternatives to a central database (which can get very expensive if your app goes viral!). Maybe use a local database so that all data is stored on the user's personal device (and, perhaps, provide an easy way to export/import that data). Some users (include me!) would actually find that to be a valuable feature! Or consider a hybrid model, where sensitive information is stored locally and general, non-personally-identifiable information (PII) is stored centrally (so you can run usage reports, etc).

Security is a balancing act between accessibility and secrecy, so there is not going to be any one-size-fits-all advice.

### Learn More

- [Firebase: Privacy and Security in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy)
- [Android: Security tips](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips)
- [Oracle: What is Data Security?](https://www.oracle.com/security/database-security/what-is-data-security/)
- [FTC: Mobile Health App Developers: FTC Best Practices](https://www.ftc.gov/business-guidance/resources/mobile-health-app-developers-ftc-best-practices)

Note that the FTC's #1 Tip is:

> **1. Minimize Data.**
>
> - **Do you need to collect and retain people’s information?** Remember, if you don’t collect data in the first place, you don’t have to go to the effort of securing it. If the data you collect is integral to your product or service, that’s fine, but take reasonable steps to secure the data you transmit and store, and delete it once you no longer have a legitimate business need to retain it. If you collect and retain it, you must protect it.
> - **Can you keep the data in a de-identified form?** When data is de-identified, it can’t be reasonably associated with a particular individual. A key to effective de-identification is to ensure that the data cannot be reasonably re-identified. For example, U.S. Department of Health and Human Services regulations require entities covered by the Health Insurance Portability and Accountability Act (HIPAA) either to remove specific identifiers, including date of birth and five-digit zip code, from protected health information or to have a privacy and data security expert determine that the risk of re-identification is “very small.” Appropriately de-identified data can protect people’s privacy while still allowing for beneficial use. For example, if your app collects geolocation information as part of an effort to map asthma outbreaks in a metropolitan area, consider whether you can provide the same functionality while maintaining and using that information in de-identified form. You can reduce the risk of re-identification of location data by not collecting highly specific location data about individual users in the first place, by limiting the number of locations stored for each user, or aggregating location data across users.
>
>   Since re-identification is always a risk, it’s important to keep up with technological developments. Publicly commit not to re-identify the data. And make sure your contracts with third parties require them to commit not to re-identify the data. Then monitor the third parties to make sure they live up to their promises.

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks for that and I'm glad I asked. I will focus my attention to learning about multi layered security and look to a professional if I can't get my head around it

Comment: @Lazza: one reason security is so "scary" and hard to get right is because those who defend data have to get *everything* right to protect the data, while an attacker only needs to find *one* hole in the system to get in. It's not an even playing field.